# How to correctly import a function from a custom module

Tags: perl, perl5.8

I need some clue on how to import correctly a function from a custom module in perl. (here person_init from the PersonInit module).

This is my folder representation :

```
TestObject.pl
Person/Person.pm
Person/PersonInit.pm
```

here is the code of TestObject.pl

```
use FindBin 1.44 qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
use warnings;        # Avertissement des messages d'erreurs
use strict;  
use Person::PersonInit;

person_init();
print('toto');
```

in Person.pm :

```
package Person;    # Nom du package, de notre classe
use warnings;        # Avertissement des messages d'erreurs
use strict;          # Vérification des déclarations
use Carp;            # Utile pour émettre certains avertissements
sub new {
  my ( $classe, $ref_arguments ) = @_;

  # Vérifions la classe
  $classe = ref($classe) || $classe;

  # Création de la référence anonyme de hachage vide (futur objet)
  my $this = {};

  # Liaison de l'objet à la classe
  bless $this, $classe;

  if (! ( defined $ref_arguments->{nom} )) {
    $ref_arguments->{nom} = 'inconnu';
  }

  $this->{_NOM}          = $ref_arguments->{nom};
  $this->{_PRENOM}       = $ref_arguments->{prenom};
  $this->{_TEL}           = $ref_arguments->{tel};
  $this->{_MAIL}           = $ref_arguments->{mail};
  $this->{_GRADE}           = $ref_arguments->{grade};
  $this->{_SEXE}         = $ref_arguments->{sexe};
  $this->{_SERVICE}         = $ref_arguments->{service};

  return $this;
}
1;                # Important, à ne pas oublier
__END__
```

and in PersonInit.pm :

```
#/usr/bin/perl
package PersonInit;
use strict;
use POSIX;
use warnings;

use FindBin 1.44 qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
use Person::Person;
use Exporter;

our @ISA= qw( Exporter );

# these CAN be exported.
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( person_init );

# these are exported by default.
our @EXPORT = qw( person_init );



sub person_init {
my ($arg) = @_;
my $Person = Person->new({
    prenom        => 'Jean',
    sexe          => 'M',
    tel => '3',
    mail  => '4',
        grade  => 'g',
        service  => 's',
  });
  print ($Person->{_NOM});
  print ('toto');
  return $Person;
 };

1;
```

So when i try to launch t i've got this error :

Undefined subroutine &main::Person_Init called at D:\Workspace\Mapping\TestObject.pl line 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For best results, the package names you use should match the package names you supply to the `use` directive. Use

```
package Person;
...
package PersonInit;
...
use Person;
use PersonInit;
```

or

```
package Person::Person;
...
package Person::PersonInit;
...
use Person::Person;
use Person::PersonInit;
```

but not

```
package Person;
...
package PersonInit;
...
use Person::Person;
use Person::PersonInit;
```

Comment: To add to this: the [use](https://perldoc.pl/functions/use) statement is documented to do two things. The first is to `require` the module, which requires passing the name that corresponds to its file path, with `::` translating to `/`. The second is to `import` from the module, which requires passing the package name. Thus for both of these to work in one `use` statement, the file path and package name must match.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're not sharing the code that you're actually using, as I'm not getting the error that you describe, but I am getting a load of other errors.

The errors I'm getting are all down to confusion over the link between module paths and package names. Because your module files are in a directory called "Person", they should actually be called "Person::Person" and "Person::PersonInit". You seem to realise that when you're loading the modules (`use Person::Person`) but not when you're naming the packages (`package Person`) or calling class methods (`Person->new(...)`).

Once I edited your files to consistently use the correct names for the packages, everything worked as expected.

I'll note that you're defining both `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK`. Your exported subroutine only needs to be in one of those.

I'm using Perl 5.26.1. From the tags on your question, it seems that you're using 5.8.something (I guess it's likely to be 5.8.8). It's possible that you're falling over a bug that has been fixed in the over thirteen years since that version was released - but, to be honest, I don't recall hearing about anything similar. Anyway, I'd urge you to upgrade to a newer version of Perl.

Comment: I can reproduce OP's problem by just running the code he provided. The only thing I need to do to fix it is replace `package PersonInit` by `package Person::PersonInit` in PersonInit.pm. (the same thing should be done in Person.pm, but that doesn't cause any error when I run it) (using perl 5.22 btw)